# Common values in sequence around a given postion

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, dynamic-programming

Came up with this question but I can't figure out if this has a non brute force answer.
What is the most optimal solution for the below question?
Consider two arrays of strings,

```
Array1 = ['2','3','156','15','*','11','13','34','65','78']
Array2 = ['3','2','15','67','13','34','54','67','89']
```

Find S1 and S2 such that `Array1.IndexOf(S1) < Array1.IndexOf('*') < Array1.IndexOf(S2) && Array2.IndexOf(S1) < Array2.IndexOf(S2)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Step 1:** Index the values of arr1 before the '*' as 1 and after the '*' as 2.

**Step 2:** Loop over the arr2 to first find the string with index as 1 and then the string with index 2.

If no pair is found then the value of S2 or both will be -1.

***Time Complexity:* O(n)**

***Space Complexity:* O(n)**

```
arr1 = ['2','3','156','15','*','11','13','34','65','78']
arr2 = ['3','2','15','67','13','34','54','67','89']

dictionary = {}

index = 1
for string in arr1:
    if(string == '*'):
        index = 2
        continue
    dictionary[string] = index
    
    
S1 = -1
S2 = -1
for string in arr2:
    value = dictionary.get(string,-1)
    if(value == 1):
        S1 = string
    elif(S1 != -1 and value == 2):
        S2 = string
        break
        
print(S1,S2)
```

Comment: Singh:  What if it repeats? I should have given a better example

Comment: Then make two different dictionaries to store which are after * and which are before.